# Dropwizard /Jersey: Pass query-parameter with multiple values as List (maybe using a filter)

Tags: list, jersey, query-string

I have clients passing in IDs like this: `/v1/path?id=1,2,3`

#### What I have and want

I have a resource class for Dropwizard/Jersey.
I'd like to show up the query-parameter `id=1,2,3` as a `List` parameter in my resource's GET method

```java
// Resource class

public List<Something> getFilteredList(@QueryParam("id") List<String> ids) {
  // filter the List<Something> based on a list of ids
}
```

Right now, the `ids` list contains 1 string which is `"1,2,3"`.

#### What I tried

I tried a filter but the query parameters given by Jersey's
`ContainerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters()`
is immutable.

#### Questions

I would like to apply a filter and change any comma separated query parameters into multi-valued parameters so that the resource method gets a list instead.

1. Is there a way to change the existing query parameters using a Jersey filter?
2. What's a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Would you like to modify the query-parameters, i.e. add to or remove from the `List id` within the method? Or what is the problem with an immutable?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is to just create a wrapper class for the list. This makes it easier to take advantage of the specified functionality of Jersey. You can see what I mean at [Passing custom type query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407999/2587435).

For example

```
public class IdFilter {
    private List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> getIds() { return ids; }

    public static IdFilter valueOf(String param) {
        IdFilter filter = new IdFilter();
        for (String id: param.split(",") {
            filter.getIds().add(id);
        }
    }
}

getFilteredList(@QueryParam("id") IdFilter ids) {
```

We don't need to do anything else. Just having the `static valueOf` is enough for Jersey to know how to parse the query string.

Answer (score 1):

3 ways to solve it:

1. use the **generic context-parameter** `UriInfo` , which is not very expressive
2. add an **explicit custom type** that can parse a comma-separated list
3. stay with `@QueryParam List<String>` requiring a **concatenated query** like `?id=1&id=2&id=3` given as URI

I would prefer the second as most-expressive, like answered already by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459437/5730279). This way you can concisely pass a single CSV like `?id=1,2,3,3` and also use a `Set` to ensure unique ID values, e.g. resulting in only `[1, 2, 3]`.

### Generic context-param `UriInfo`

One way would be to use a generic parameter `@Context UriInfo` to get the list in the method's body:

```java
public List<Something> getFilteredList( @Context UriInfo uriInfo ) {

  List<String> idList = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().get("id"); // before was @QueryParam("id")
  System.out.println("idList: " + idList);
  
  // filter a given list by ids
  var somethingFiltered = getSomethingList().stream()
    .filter(s -> idList.contains(s.getId()))
    .collect(toList());
  
  return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(somethingFiltered).build();
}
```

See the tutorial in Java Vogue(2015): [QueryParam Annotation In Jersey -](https://www.javavogue.com/2015/04/queryparam-annotation-in-jersey/)

### Custom type with `static valueOf(String)` factory-method

The other way is to design a custom type which can be constructed using a String:

```java
class IdSet {
  
  Set<String> values;

  // a factory method, can also be named valueOf
  public static IdSet fromString(String commaSeparated) {
    return new HashSet( Arrays.asList( commaSeparated.split(",") ) );
  }
}

public List<Something> getFilteredList(@QueryParam("id") IdSet ids) {
  System.out.println("ids (Set): " + ids.values);
  
  // filter a given list by ids
  var somethingFiltered = getSomethingList().stream()
    .filter(s -> ids.values.contains(s.getId()))
    .collect(toList());
  
  return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(somethingFiltered).build();
}
```

See Jersey's JavaDocs for [`@QueryParam`](https://jakartaee.github.io/rest/apidocs/2.1.6//javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html):

> The type T of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
> 3. Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single `String` argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
> 4. Have a registered implementation of `ParamConverterProvider` that returns a `ParamConverter` instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.
> 5. Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2, 3 or 4 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

### Use a collection interface with multiple key-value pairs

When the calling client uses following URI pattern: `/something?id=1&id=2&id=3` then JAX-RS can deserialize them to a single parameter of `List<String> id` having given multiple elements:

```java
public List<Something> getFilteredList(@QueryParam("id") List<String> ids) {
  System.out.println("ids : "+ids);
  
  // filter a given list by ids
  var somethingFiltered = getSomethingList().stream()
    .filter(s -> ids.contains(s.getId()))
    .collect(toList());
  
  return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(somethingFiltered).build();
}
```

See Mkyong: [JAX-RS @QueryParam example](https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/) where explained the multiple occurrences of `orderBy` in the GET query:

> @QueryParam will convert the query parameter “orderBy=age&orderBy=name” into java.util.List automatically.

### See also

- [Handling Multiple Query Parameters in Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154861/handling-multiple-query-parameters-in-jersey?rq=1)
- [Deserializing List<Map<String, String>> QueryParam in jersey 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467474/deserializing-listmapstring-string-queryparam-in-jersey-1?rq=1)
- [Jersey, @QueryParam List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964958/jersey-queryparam-liststring/30965013#30965013)